# Google Drive equivalent for S3 Signed Request URLs

Tags: amazon-s3, google-drive-api

How can I create a request URL for a Google Drive resource such that the associated authentication information in the URL is valid only for that object. For objects stored on S3, one can create a signed request URL with an expiration date (as explained here https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1174/). I am looking for something similar for Google Drive. All I have been able to find to-date is to append the access_token to the downloadUrl of a file. The downloadUrl does expire after a while but the access_token can be used to access the owner's entire drive (correct me if I am wrong here).

Complete Scenario: A user (lets call him Bob) grants my app access to their Google Drive. I fetch a list of all the videos on their Google Drive. Bob then selects a couple of videos and asks my app to share it with another user (lets call her Cindy). Cindy gets an email with the link to a page on my app that should show her the videos. Since my app has an access_token for Bob's GDrive, it retrieves the temporary downloadUrl from Google Drive, appends the access_token to it and shows the videos on a web page using these links. Cindy can now grab the access_token from her browser and break into Bob's GDrive. I do not want Cindy to be able to break into Bob's account.

The above can be avoided if the video is set to "Anyone with the Link" but that that does not sit well with Bob. For images, I proxy the data through my server but for videos I can not afford this. If I could get a `token` that was temporarily valid only for the shared videos, I would be golden.

Comment: The correct platform for what you are trying to do is Google Cloud Storage, which does have signed URL functionality and is intended for applications including serving assets, not Google Drive, which is intended for personal use, for file sharing.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot then I would have to pay for the Google Cloud Storage instead of the user paying for their Google Drive and my app offering a free service on top of that.

Comment: I see... Bob is not you.  My mistake.  Not sure why a user would allow a 3rd party app to share a file that they could share themselves from Google Drive.

Comment: ...but isn't this what you need? https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#downloading_files_in_a_browser

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the app does more than just that (but I left it out to simplify the question). I have read the page you linked to and that is exactly what I am doing for images (and bearing the cost of having the image data proxied from my servers, so that I don't have to expose the access_token). Unfortunately, I can not afford to do the same for videos.